# Field synchronization in Play! Controllers

Tags: java, synchronization, playframework, lazy-initialization

Consider a situation when we have a Controller with 2 action methods that use same controller field. This field should be lazily initialized.

```
public class SomeController extends Controller {
    private static volatile Resource resource;

    private static Resource getResource() {
        if (resource == null) {
            synchronized (SomeController.class) {
                if (resource == null) {
                    resource = new Resource();
                }
            }
        }

        return resource;
    }

    public static void action1() {
        getResource().doSomeAction();
    }

    public static void action2() {
        getResource().doSomeAnotherAction();
    }

}
```

What are better ways of synchronizing common resources using Play Framework? Consider that resource should be lazy initialized.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference with lazy-loaded class(field) in Play or in others servlet containers (tomcat etc) which use regular servlets. Your code with double-check-locking should works fine. But I suggest you to avoid double-check-locking (even it's not broken), simply make your method synchronized.